# react native import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel" not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I install  **npm i @types/react-native-snap-carousel** and **version is 3.8.5**
My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "olivers",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "test:e2e": "detox test -c ios.sim.debug",
    "build:e2e": "detox build -c ios.sim.debug",
    "ci:test:e2e": "detox test -c ios.sim.release -l verbose --cleanup",
    "ci:build:e2e": "detox build -c ios.sim.release",
    "compile": "tsc --noEmit -p . --pretty",
    "format": "npm-run-all format:*",
    "format:js": "prettier --write \"app/**/*.js\"",
    "format:json": "prettier --write \"app/**/*.json\"",
    "format:md": "prettier --write \"**/*.md\"",
    "format:ts": "prettier --write \"app/**/*.ts{,x}\"",
    "lint": "eslint index.js app storybook test --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx && yarn format",
    "patch": "patch-package",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c ./storybook",
    "test": "jest",
    "adb": "adb reverse tcp:9090 tcp:9090 && adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000 && adb reverse tcp:9001 tcp:9001 && adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
    "postinstall": "node ./bin/postInstall",
    "build-ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios",
    "build-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "clean": "react-native-clean-project",
    "clean-all": "npx react-native clean-project-auto"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "~6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "~6.0.1",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "apisauce": "2.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expo": "^43.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-localization": "11.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "3.8.0",
    "mobx": "6.1.8",
    "mobx-react-lite": "3.2.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "5.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-bottom-action-sheet": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-helper": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "3.8.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-switch-toggle": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-sync-localstorage": "^0.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1",
    "reactotron-mst": "3.1.3",
    "reactotron-react-js": "^3.3.7",
    "reactotron-react-native": "5.0.0",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "validate.js": "0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "6.1.10",
    "@storybook/react-native": "5.3.23",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "5.3.23",
    "@types/i18n-js": "3.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.19",
    "@types/react": "16.14.0",
    "@types/react-native": "0.63.40",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.10.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "detox": "17.14.5",
    "eslint": "^8.4.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "7.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.10.0",
    "fbjs-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-circus": "25.5.4",
    "jest-expo": "^43.0.1",
    "jetifier": "1.6.6",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "patch-package": "6.2.2",
    "postinstall-prepare": "1.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "react-devtools-core": "4.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.6.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.16.3",
    "react-powerplug": "1.0.0",
    "solidarity": "^3.0.4",
    "typescript": "4.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/setup.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/e2e"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|expo|expo-linear-gradient|@react-native|@react-native-async-storage|@react-navigation|@storybook|@react-native-community|expo-localization)"
    ]
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 100,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/olivers.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/olivers.xcworkspace -scheme olivers -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build -destination 'name=iPhone 11'",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "name": "iPhone 11",
          "os": "iOS 13.2"
        }
      },
      "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/olivers.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/olivers.xcworkspace -scheme olivers -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build -destination 'name=iPhone 11'",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "name": "iPhone 11",
          "os": "iOS 13.2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:react-native/all",
      "standard",
      "prettier",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint",
      "react",
      "react-native"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      },
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "settings": {
      "react": {
        "pragma": "React",
        "version": "detect"
      }
    },
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": false,
      "jasmine": false,
      "beforeAll": false,
      "afterAll": false,
      "beforeEach": false,
      "afterEach": false,
      "test": false,
      "expect": false,
      "describe": false,
      "jest": false,
      "it": false
    },
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/indent": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-object-literal-type-assertion": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 0,
      "comma-dangle": 0,
      "multiline-ternary": 0,
      "no-undef": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 0,
      "no-use-before-define": "off",
      "quotes": 0,
      "react-native/no-raw-text": 0,
      "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
      "react/prop-types": "off",
      "space-before-function-paren": 0
    }
  }
}
```

So i check installing so many time and did remove node_modules and did npm install many time

**The error massage is**

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-snap-carousel from /Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/app/screens/welcome/event-banner.tsx: react-native-snap-carousel could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../../../node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  3 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
  4 | import BottomSheet from "reanimated-bottom-sheet"
> 5 | import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel"
    |                       ^
  6 |
  7 | const EventBannerSheet: React.FC = () => {
  8 |   const sheetRef = useRef(null)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:129:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at /Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async addDependency (/Users/jeonchangmin/Desktop/newdir/olivers/olivers/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
```

Also I did 4 steps

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

But still not working..... Someone Help me???

Last My event-banner.tsx is

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Dimensions } from "react-native"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
import BottomSheet from "reanimated-bottom-sheet"
import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel"

const EventBannerSheet: React.FC = () => {
  const sheetRef = useRef(null)
  const carouselRef = useRef(null)
  const SliderWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width
  const [activeIndex, setActivateIndex] = useState(0)
  const [carouselState, setCarouselState] = useState([
    {
      title: "Item 1",
      text: "Text 1",
    },
    {
      title: "Item 2",
      text: "Text 2",
    },
    {
      title: "Item 3",
      text: "Text 3",
    },
    {
      title: "Item 4",
      text: "Text 4",
    },
    {
      title: "Item 5",
      text: "Text 5",
    },
  ])

  const _onPressCarousel = (index: any) => {
    // here handle carousel press
    carouselRef.current.snapToItem(index)
  }

  const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          _onPressCarousel(index)
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          borderRadius: 20,
          height: 300,
          padding: 50,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  const renderContent = () => (
    <View style={styles.bottomSheet}>
      {/* <View style={styles.sheetTextContainer}>
        <Image source={require("./event.jpeg")} style={{ height: "90%", width: "90%" }} />
      </View> */}
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Carousel
          layout={"default"}
          ref={carouselRef}
          data={carouselState}
          sliderWidth={SliderWidth}
          itemWidth={300}
          renderItem={_renderItem}
          useScrollView
          onSnapToItem={(index) => setActivateIndex(index)}
          activeSlideAlignment="center"
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.sheetCloseContainer}>
        <Text
          style={{ color: "gray" }}
          onPress={() => {
            sheetRef.current.snapTo(2)
          }}
        >
          오늘 하루 보지않기
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => sheetRef.current.snapTo(2)}>
          <Text>닫기</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )

  return (
    <>
      <BottomSheet
        initialSnap={1}
        ref={sheetRef}
        enabledContentGestureInteraction={false}
        snapPoints={[450, 350, 0]}
        borderRadius={10}
        renderContent={renderContent}
      />
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomSheet: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 25,
    height: 440,
  },

  sheetTextContainer: {
    height: 270,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
    borderRadius: 10,
  },

  sheetText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "white",
  },

  sheetCloseContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
})

export default EventBannerSheet
```

Comment: https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only install

```
npm install --save @types/react-native-snap-carousel
```

because i use typeScript... But i must install

```
$ npm install --save react-native-snap-carousel
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after I installed `react-native-snap-carousel`, it wasn't included in `package.json`. So, I added the following line to `dependencies` in `package.json`

```json
...
dependencies: {
    ...
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    ...
}
```

Then, I ran the following commands

```bash
npm install react-native-snap-carousel
npm install @types/react-native-snap-carousel

npx react-native run-android
```